# No Module Error in Pycharm ONLY When Using A Notebook

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, python-3.10

I am trying to import a method from a module outside the current module.
While I can do this from a script without any issue, when I try it from inside a Jupyter notebook, it fails. How do you suggest I investigate the issue?

Example: Imagine these be my directories.

```
- module_1
--- __inte__.py
--- my_lib.py
- module_2
--- __inte__.py
--- script_which_calls_from_my_lib.py
--- notebook_which_calls_from_my_lib.ipynb
```

And I import the same way in both files (.py and .ipynb):

```
from module_1.my_lib import method_x
```

In the example above, `script_which_calls_from_my_lib.py` imports the methods without any issue, but `notebook_which_calls_from_my_lib.ipynb` returns the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_1'
```

**Note**: This seems to be an issue only within this project (in PyCharm). That is, when I tried to reproduced a minimal working example in a new project, it worked without an issue.

**Note:** I have cleaned up this project as much as I could. I removed `venv` and created a new one with only Jupyter installed, I closed the project in PyCharm, etc.

---

### Edit

It seems that PyCharm 22.3 might be the cause of this error:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-4251
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57823

Comment: How did you import the `module_1`?

Comment: This is do with the incorrect way of importing the module. Can you also tell how are you importing?

Comment: I'm importing within the script the same way that I did in the notebook: `from module_1.my_lib import method_x` @AshishKumar , @codester_09